# Why does Liouville's Theorem imply that there are no 1-1 holomorphic maps from $\mathbb{C}$ to $D(0,1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Liouville's Theorem say that every bounded entire function is constant. I can't see why one of the consequences of it is there is no 1-1 holomorphic maps from $\mathbb{C}$ onto $D(0,1)$, where $D(0,1)$ denoted the unit disk center at $0$.

Comment: Under such conditions $|f|<1$ is holomorphic all over the plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f : \mathbb{C} \to D(0, 1)$ is a holomorphic function, then it is entire (its domain is $\mathbb{C}$), and it is bounded (its codomain is $D(0, 1) = \{w \in \mathbb{C} \mid |w| < 1\}$). By Liouville's theorem, $f$ must be constant. As constant functions are not one-to-one, there is no one-to-one holomorphic map $f : \mathbb{C} \to D(0, 1)$.

Comment: Does it also means that there are no 1-1 holomorphic map from $\mathbb{C}$ onto any open region $U$? Since I can always contain $U$ in some open disk.

Comment: If $U$ is contained in some open disk, you are only thinking about bounded domains. The answer is yes. More generally, there are no one-to-one holomorphic functions $f : \mathbb{C} \to U$ where $U$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese If $U$ lacks at least two points, then we can use Pickard's theorem, but how can we conclude that $f$ can't be one-to-one if domain omits a single point?

Comment: @Wojowu: As $f(\mathbb{C})$ is open, connected, simply connected, and $f(\mathbb{C}) \neq \mathbb{C}$ (as $f(\mathbb{C}) \subseteq U \subset \mathbb{C}$), $f(\mathbb{C})$ is biholomorphic to $D(0, 1)$ by the Riemann Mapping Theorem. But then $f$ composed with a biholomorphism $f(\mathbb{C}) \to D(0, 1)$ would give an injective map $\mathbb{C} \to D(0, 1)$, but no such map exists.